# nuget restore failure for vs solution

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

We currently get the following error on the build server with no related changes we can notice. What could be wrong or where should we start debug it?

```
...
RestorePackages:
  "E:\AzureBuildAgentWorkingFolder\2\s\Server\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive  -solutionDir "E:\AzureBuildAgentWorkingFolder\2\s\Server\ "
  All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): Error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, version 2.4.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.
...
```

We have checked and the folder and files for the signalr (Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, version 2.4.0) package exists.

I have tried:

- clean entire build folder
- adding msbuild restore to pipeline
- different nuget versions from 4 -> 5
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client version 2.4.0 and 2.4.1
- manual build with VS on the build server (works)

Comment: Have you tried deleting your nuget packages folder for the solution and then running a restore of the nuget packages or relaunching the build?  
Restoring could be done via "MSBuild /t:restore" or "nuget restore" or "dotnet restore"
[Microsoft Nuget Restore Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore)

Comment: yes, doing it manually works, but not through the pipeline. I have also tested a total clean of the folder. This is the only nuget package of multiple which are failing. No matter the order I have them so its something with this specific package.

Comment: Have you tried removing the package from the solution, saving the solution then adding it back?  Also, are you positive that the packages.json file is actually getting checked into the repository?  We've seen it before where updates to that file, because they are done via VS and not manually, don't register with some source control systems and plugins.  We then need to manually check out the file and check it back in.